# How to convert .sdkmesh file to .x file?

Tags: directx

Is is possible to convert .sdkmesh file to .x file? I found only reverse of this is possible. If this is possible, please share link to that site/code?

Comment: Decoding an ``SDKMESH`` file isn't all that difficult, but the question is why do you want it in the legacy ``.x`` file format?

Comment: Because I have many .sdkmesh files already created to use in my project. All these files are binary files which I want to edit now (using softwares like Autodesk, 3D Max or Maya). For this reason I want equivalent .x files which I can open with above softwares and then able to modify them. Is there any converter available?  @ChuckWalbourn

Comment: So you don't really care what format the ``sdkmesh`` gets dumped out as except that it is something you can load in an editor. What happened to the original source files you used to create the ``sdkmesh`` files in the first place?

Comment: Yes somehow I want to open these files into an editor. I only have .sdkmesh version of files as I got these files from third party, I don't have their original .x source files.